# Getting average data from list using Collectors.averagingInt java

Tags: java, lambda, collectors

I have a code with two different methods, but one of them is working and other is not compilled, I don`t get what is wrong.
Here is the code:

```
    public class CollectorOperations {

    public int averageAgeInt(List<Person> persons) {
        return persons.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(person -> person.getAge()));
    }

    public double averageAgeDouble(List<Person> personList, int i) {
        return personList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(person -> person.getAge()));
    }
}



class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

The only difference between this two methods is return type, when return type is `int` I can't get `person.age()` from lambda expression, but when I change return type to `double` it's working.

P.S. 
sorry for my english.

Comment: `Collectors.averagingInt` provides `Double`, which totally makes sense for an average, so why would you expect an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not compiling due a type mismatch here:

```
persons.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(person -> person.getAge()));
```

That operation returns an object of the type Double, but your method is defined to return an integer.

The reason is that a Double object can  not be cast into an int, but since that is a Double object, you can get the integer value calling the method `Double#intValue()`

You need to do something like

```
return persons.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(person -> person.getAge())).intValue();
```

---

I don’t get why you have a parameter `int i` in the method **averageAgeDouble** (the variable is never used), so you can define a more elegant way if you get rid off that variable:

```
public int averageAgeInt(List<Person> persons) {
    return (int) averageAgeDouble(persons);
}

public double averageAgeDouble(List<Person> personList) {
    return personList.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingInt(person -> person.getAge()));
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, when I looked in java-doc I understood that method averagingInt returns Collector<T,?,Double> and it`s not working with Integer values.